# I can't run applet on my firefox browser

Tags: firefox, java, netbeans

I am a new user in Ubuntu 13.10 , and I want to run an applet so,I installed Java Develop Kit 7u45 with netbeans 7.4 and I can run applet from netbeans but not from browser because of security setting.I search about my problem and I change my security setting to low and every thing remain with out an change help me please

Answer (score 5):

Default settings of java control panel is "High". Current security policy of java will **never let you run java untrusted applets using a browser**. Only applets having a certificate and proper permissions attribute can be ran on a browser.

To test an applet you can use IDE like eclipse or netbeans, that you already did. Other way is **`appletviewer`**. It comes with  Java Develop Kit. To use it you need to write a sample `html` file.

You can run the applet using the html file from a terminal as,

```
appletviewer /path/to/sample.html
```

**Content of `sample.html`**

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<body>
    <applet width=300 height=300 code="Appletname.class"> </applet> 
</body>
</html>
```

Here I am assuming your applet name is `Appletname.class` and it is in the same directory as `sample.html`. Your applet viewer window size would be 300x300.

**How to run applets with firefox**

- Update your jdk, latest is [jdk-7u51](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
- Install/Enable java plugins for firefox, [check plugin here](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/)
- [**Never recommend, Do it at your own risk**] Open Java Control Panel, Keep your security settings to Medium, it will allow all applications to run except applications that request all permissions.<sup>[[source]](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml)</sup>

[image: screenshot of java control panel]

Comment: Thank you for your answer now I used applet viewer and I able to run both local and internet applets but according to your answer I can run applet from internet without using applet viewer but also I can not do that for example :http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/Java/applets.htm does not run on my browser for the same reason

Comment: That seem to be different issue. you did not clearly mentioned that in your question. Anyway you can try after updating java and don't forget to enable java plugins for firefox.